# Using Recursion to count how many palindromes in a string

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, palindrome

I know that this question has been asked quite a bit, but the issue I have is slightly different. This assignment requires me to use recursion to not verify if a string is a palindrome - but to verify how many palindromes are in one string (return as an 'int'). I currently have a code that does that but when I want it to count how many palindromes there are in 'appal' it returns 0 when it should return 2 (appa, pp). I would really appreciate it if any of you guys can help me with this issue since its due in a couple of hours thank you!
Here's my code:

```
function countPalindromes(string, count) {
  if (string.length <= 1) {
    return count;
  }

  let [ firstLetter ] = string;
  let lastLetter = string[string.length - 1];

  if (firstLetter === lastLetter) {
    let stringWithoutFirstAndLastLetters = string.substring(1, string.length - 1);
    return countPalindromes(stringWithoutFirstAndLastLetters, count + 1);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

console.log(countPalindromes("kayak", 0));
console.log(countPalindromes("aya", 0));
console.log(countPalindromes("appal", 0));
```

Comment: Your algorithm counts in from the ends to the middle. `appal` doesn't fit the pattern of even finding the first palindrome.  Just like `kayaks` wouldn't either, but `kayak` does.

Comment: how can I make it fit then? @Marc

Comment: I find [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-palindrome-sub-strings-string/) very useful. You may want to take a look

Comment: @dshung1997 i saw that but it doesn't include javascript?

Comment: Yeah. it's the algorithm and once you understand the way the problem is solved, you can translate it into Javascript. If it seems hard, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BShYX4aq22I) is a video that I previously saw